# Conditionally set the xlim or axis limits when making plots in a loop in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im trying to set up a loop for making alot of plots in R.
My code looks like this:

```
    for (i in unique(NewAnalyse$PointID)){
  df = subset(NewAnalyse, NewAnalyse$PointID == i)
  gi <- ggplot(df, aes(x=GeoProbe_OIHPT.PAH16_Concentration ,y=GeoProbe_OIHPT.Depth_m_Clay))+
    geom_point(aes(colour=PAH16_int)) +
    labs(x = "PAH16 Concentration (mg/kg)", y = "Depth, clay (m)")+
    scale_y_continuous(trans="reverse", breaks=seq(0, 11, 1)) +
    xlim(0,NA)+
    scale_color_manual("Cons mg/kg ts", 
                       values=c("<250"="forestgreen", 
                                ">250"="red3"))+
    facet_grid(vars(PointID), vars(PointCorner))+
    geom_hline(yintercept =0.0)+
    geom_hline(yintercept =0.5)+
    geom_hline(yintercept =1.5)+
    geom_hline(yintercept =3)+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1)) +
    ggtitle("Point", i)
    ggsave(gi, filename = paste("plot__Point_", i,".png"), width = 20, height = 20, units = "cm")
}
```

What i would like to do is make a set xlim intervals, so that the x-axis is always either 0-100, 0-500 or 0-5000 based on highest `x=GeoProbe_OIHPT.PAH16_Concentration` value in each DF.

Is that even possible?

Hope someone can help me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved by setting the limits conditionally via an `if`-statement. Personally I prefer to use lists and `lapply` or `purrr::map` or `purrr::walk` to make plots in a loop instead of using `for` but the approach could also be used with a `for`-loop:

Using `mtcars` as example dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mtcars_split <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)

plot_function <- function(df, i) {
  xlim <- if (max(df$mpg) < 20) {
    xlim(0, 20)
  } else if (max(df$mpg) < 30) {
    xlim(0, 30)
  } else {
    xlim(0, 40)
  }
  ggplot(df, aes(x=mpg ,y=hp))+
    geom_point(aes(colour=am)) +
    xlim +
    ggtitle("Point", i)
  ggsave(filename = paste("plot_cyl_", i,".png"), width = 20, height = 20, units = "cm")  
}
```

Loop over the splitted dataframe using `purrr::iwalk`

```
purrr::iwalk(mtcars_split, plot_function)
```

or using a `for` loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(mtcars_split)) {
  plot_function(mtcars_split[[i]], names(mtcars_split)[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. 
And thanks for showing me purrr, thats gonna save me some time down the line, because this way of looping it seems alot faster